# Source of build error "expected primary-expression before 'float' " in simple implementation of inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, syntax

I cannot seem to find why I am getting the build error

> expected primary-expression before "float"

In this implementation...

```
using namespace std;

class Point{
public:

Point(float X = 0.0, float Y = 0.0);

void set(float X, float Y);
void setX(float X);
void setY(float Y);

void get(float * P_x, float * P_y);
float getX();
float getY();

float * pX();
float * pY();

SDL_Point returnSDL();

private:
float x;
float y;
};


class Vector : public Point{
public:
    Vector(float X = 0.0, float Y = 0.0);
};

 ///The errors occur in this constructor...
Vector::Vector(float X, float Y) : Point(float X, float Y){

}
```

Im still learning about the finer points of classes and would appreciate any help. I know it has something to do with the inheritance because when `Vector`  doesn't inherit `Point` the program builds normally. As far as i can tell this is the correct syntax and implementation of inheritance. Web help i have found cannot answer so far.

Comment: `: Point(float X, float Y)`-> `: Point(X, Y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ///The errors occur in this constructor...
> Vector::Vector(float X, float Y) : Point(float X, float Y){
>
> }
> ```

There are two similar constructions in this fragment of code:
`Vector::Vector(float X, float Y)` and `: Point(float X, float Y)`:

- the first one (`Vector::Vector(float X, float Y)`) is the declaration of the constructor of class `Vector`;
- the other one (`: Point(float X, float Y)`) is a function call; a call of the constructor of class `Point`; notice the colon (`:`) that introduce the list of member initializers.

Now, if you see the difference between the two (function/method declaration or definition vs. function/method call) you can find the error yourself: the compiler expects expressions and not types in the arguments list of the call to the `Point::Point()` constructor.

```
// Look, ma! No errors!
Vector::Vector(float X, float Y) : Point(X, Y) {

}
```

For more information take a look at the documentation page about [constructors and member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing declaring a function and using a function.  When you declare a function you need to tell the compiler what the types of the parameters are.

```
Vector::Vector(float X, float Y)
```

Now in the member initialization part you have

```
: Point(float X, float Y)
```

Here you are adding types to the function call which is not what you want to do.  When you call a function you just pass the values/variables to it.

```
: Point( X, Y)
        ^  ^ no type here as we just pass X and Y to the Point constructor.
```